# How can I escape the my c# script to add html tags?

Tags: c#, html, escaping

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cptUID")==selectedCpt.Value ? "TRUE" :  <add font tags here> "FALSE" <closing font tag> %></span></td>
```

My goal is to change the text color in one of the cases. I tried expierementing with different escape strings and they are all flagged by the compiler.
thank you.

Comment: It would be much easier on everyone involved if you got away from this inline script malarkey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just do this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cptUID") == selectedCpt.Value 
    ? "TRUE" : "<font color=\"red\">FALSE</font>" %></span></td>
```

Or this:

```
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "DataItem.cptUID") == selectedCpt.Value 
    ? "TRUE" : @"<font color=""red"">FALSE</font>" %></span></td>
```

**Further Reading**

- [string (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.90%29.aspx): Contains many examples of escaping regular and verbatim strings